# grouping by ID, shift all rows up one and leave NA for last row

Tags: r

I have a dataset in long format organized by four times per subject. When grouping by subject number, I'm trying to shift all rows up by 1 and then leave the last observation for each subject with NA.

I tried this, but it shifted it down by 1, instead of up by 1.

```
data_long_new <- data_long_new[, variable_lag:=c(NA, variable[-.N]), by=subject_id]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it.

```
data_long_new <- data_long %>% group_by(subject_id) %>% mutate(next.variable = lead(variable, order_by=subject_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the fact u're using `data.table`

```r
data_long[, next.variable:=shift(variable, type="lead"), by= subject_id]
```

also you're code is almost correct:

```r
data_long_new[, variable_lead:=c(variable[-1],NA), by=subject_id]
```